# difficult SQL subquery to count something

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I'm developing an jQuery mobile app and therefore I need to count something in my database. I spend hours and hours and ask some fellow students, but it doesn't work.

Database: PostgreSQL with Subqueries

**For example: the structure of one of my subqueries:**

```
app.get('/getNumber', function(req, res) {
    getFromDB("SELECT COUNT(p.*) AS rooms 
               FROM park_rooms p 
               WHERE p.park_house_id = " + req.param("house"), req, res)
})
```

---

### **And here comes the problem:**

[image]

[Larger description image: klick](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140112/iaof7uwh.png)

---

### **What I need:**

I want to **count** all `result=0` in the table classification with the `park_house_id = 0`.

**BUT**: only the `park_room_id`s with the **highest frame** and **no multiple park_room_ids**

Are there some database experts, that can show me a subquery to solve this problem?

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: PostgreSQL, but I'm using Subqueries (SELECT FROM WHERE ...) to get data

Comment: so what's your expected result with the above data?

Comment: I've marked the data blue (park_house_id = 1). The expected result should be 3, because there are 3x result=0 in table classification with park_house_id=1 and max frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first we want rows from `classification` that belong to `park_house_id = 1`, so what we do is inner join `classification` with `park_room` where this condition is true by using:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM park_room pr
 INNER JOIN classification c ON c.park_room_id = pr.id
 WHERE pr.park_house_id = 1
```

Now, for each `park_room_id` we want to find out the maximum frame number, we do this by using `MAX()` function and a `GROUP BY park_room.id` or in our case we've aliased `park_room` as `pr` so `GROUP BY pr.id`.  And we alias the maximum frame number as maxframe

```
 SELECT pr.id,max(c.frame) as maxframe
 FROM park_room pr
 INNER JOIN classification c ON c.park_room_id = pr.id
 WHERE pr.park_house_id = 1
 GROUP BY pr.id
```

Finally, we want to count the rows in `classification` that have this `maxframe` number as `frame` for each `park_room_id` and a `result` of zero(0). So we inner join this above result back with `classification` to check the if `result = 0` and simply COUNT the park_room_id(s) that meet this condition. So our final query is. (notice the query above is now a subquery to produce a table with an alias of `maxframe` in our final query).

```
SELECT COUNT(park_room_id)
FROM classification c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT pr.id,max(c.frame) as maxframe
 FROM park_room pr
 INNER JOIN classification c ON c.park_room_id = pr.id
 WHERE pr.park_house_id = 1
 GROUP BY pr.id)as maxframe
ON c.park_room_id = maxframe.id AND frame=maxframe.maxframe
WHERE result = 0
```

please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07f73/4/0)

Comment: Always nice to explain it a little to help people learn, not just copy code, but eh, whatever works for you.

Comment: @CraigRinger, thanks for mentioning that. I edited my answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
   select 
     park_room_id, 
     max(frame) maxframe
   from classification 
   group by park_room_id
  ) 
select
  count(*)
from
  classification c inner join park_room r on
  c.park_room_id = r.id 
  and 
  c.result = 0 join t on t.park_room_id = c.park_room_id
where
  r.park_house_id = 1
  and
  c.frame = t.maxframe
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/44911/2)